# Aligning Media objects in boostrap, so as to swap text around image

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Twitter boostrap [example](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#media-default) to make the text of the media object to wrap around an image. However this is not working as can be seen in the image below.
[image]

The site can be accessed at http://cfcmelbourne.org/

How do I make the text wrap around the image when the screen width shrinks ?

Comment: But even if you already have the right answer. This type of text wrap is not recomend it. As style it looks always terrible and it doens't help the reading. (it's ok if your image were floating right, then the reading flow is natural)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert your image under the `media-body` element then set it as `float:left;`

```css
.media-body a {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 2px
}
```

```html
<div class="media">
                       
                       <div class="media-body">
                           <a href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5iYmtBItC8" style="
    float: left;
">
                               <img class="media-object" alt="64x64" style="width: 164px; height: 100px;" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/-5iYmtBItC8/0.jpg" data-holder-rendered="true">
                           </a> <h4 class="media-heading" id="media-heading">A dwelling place for God: 1 The secure Church</h4>
                            Santosh talks about fundamental concepts related to the faith. He address the nature of our faith, showing, how it is the foundation of everything we receive from God. In relation to faith, Santosh Poonen also talks about a dwelling place for God.
                       </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The overflow: hidden in .media-body prevents the text from wrapping around the image.

One way to solve this would be to do this :

```
.media-body {
    overflow: visible;
}
```